# "and" vs "or" combination, what's the priority?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions

I'm confused by some explanations contain both "and" and "or" from the dictionaries when I'm learning English.
For example, an explanation says "quickly and suddenly or loudly".
should it mean "(quickly) and (suddenly or loudly)"
or “(quickly and suddenly) or (loudly)”?

Comment: I have no good sources upon which to base this, but my usage has always made generous and specific usage of commas to make it perfectly clear exactly what is meant in cases just such as this. As is such, it would be clear what was meant if `quickly and suddenly, or loudly`, or alternatively `quickly, and suddenly or loudly`, were to have been used instead. Which is to say that unfortunately your intuition is really the only possible way to solve what was intended by the author in cases like this.

Comment: What word is this a definition of?

Comment: Hi, it's one of the definitions of word "sharply". It's just an example and I'm sure I read a lot of definitions like that during my vocabulary learning progress, both from Oxford or Longman dictionary.

Comment: I don't think there's a consistent rule. You have to use common sense to determine which grouping is likely. E.g. "suddenly" and "quickly" seem to be more closely related than "suddenly" and "loudly" are. It doesn't make sense to group (suddenly or loudly), so your second grouping is intended.

Comment: Notice that "quick" and "sudden" both refer to time, so "quickly and suddenly" is a more detailed description of the time aspect than either word by itself.